# Watch attribute changes with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to fire an event when a div's attribute changes. I came across this plugin http://meetselva.github.io/attrchange/ and it seems to do the trick. The only problem is that it's firing the event multiple times. For example, if I do:

```
$("#sgPluginBox").attrchange({

    callback: function(evnt) {
        if(evnt.attributeName == "style") { 
            alert('test');
        }
    }
});
```

it will show eight alert boxes. I have no idea why it's doing that. I need it to only show one alert box when the style attribute is changed. Any suggestions?

EDIT:

Not the most elegant solution but it looks like using $.one(alert('test')) did the trick.

Comment: Is your `$("#test").attrchange();` code is i a loop or something that would cause multiple instance of it?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/grcg8etv/ It works fine for me. As previous comment said something else seems to be happening. Are you attaching the event more than once? http://jsfiddle.net/grcg8etv/1/

Comment: note disclaimer about watching style in the plugin docs. A demo that replicates your issue would help

Comment: The attrchange(); isn't in a loop or anything. The div I am watching is part of a modal gallery that comes up when an image on the page is clicked. The style attribute doesn't change multiple times though.

Comment: I updated my post with a url where you can see the actual problem.

Comment: Where exactly should we be clicking to experience the problem on your website?

Comment: On any of the post images.

Comment: Maybe there are 8 style changes... Add the line you've removed from the question - `trackValues: true`, and check the properties `evnt.oldValue` and `evnt.newValue`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `MutationObserver`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var target = $("#test").get(0);

  // create an observer instance
  var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    if (mutations.length) {
      alert(mutations[0].attributeName + " changed")
      target.innerHTML = target.style.fontSize;
      // disconnect `observer`
      this.disconnect()
    }
  });

  // configuration of the observer:
  var config = {
    attributes: true
  };

  // pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
  observer.observe(target, config);

  $("#test").attr("style", "font-size:36px");
  setTimeout(function() {
      $("#test").attr("style", "font-size:52px")
      .html($("#test").css("fontSize"))
    },
    1000)

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="test" style="font-size:20px;">abc</div>
```

Comment: The plugin already uses `MutationObserver` - `jQuery("#sgPluginBox").data("attrchange-obs") instanceof MutationObserver // == true`

Comment: @Andreas _"The plugin already uses `MutationObserver`"_ Not tried plugin ; though plugin not appear necessary to achieve expected results. Could call `.disconnect()` to stop observing element attribute changes if any mutation records exist